# HTML Paste Components ID (Classic Content)

Tags: marketing-cloud, classic

I need to find where MC is storing the ID (key) associated with the HTML Paste Components in "Classic Content".

For Content Blocks is clear (Element --> Properties --> ID), but for HTML Paste elements in properties is not being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

For classic content, the ID is stored in 2 places.

1. In the 'Content Properties' section - labeled as 'Content Area ID'
   (check next to the content area and click 'properties' next to 'move' in top bar.
   [image]
2. Via the URL to the content area. I usually recommend right clicking it and then pasting it to notepad or similar. From there you grab the numbers after '?cid=' and that is your content ID (do not include the # if it is on your URL, this is not part of the id)

   For example:
   `https://members.exacttarget.com/Content/Libraries/ContentAreaList.aspx?cid=123456789#`

   the content area ID would be `123456789`.

Comment: Thanks Gortonington for your comments. This is the way I used to do for retreiving IDs from Content Area elements. But , I don't see the way to use this process for HTML Paste elements because when you click in the elements, the Properties option is not displaying the ID and the URL associated in not being displayed  because the element is displayed embedded in the page. Any advise on the process to follow for this HTmL Paste elements will be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: The above is for an HTML Paste content area in Classic content. If you are not seeing this info, I would talk to your Admin or to SFMC global support as to my knowledge that info should be there. I am not sure what you mean by "URL associated in not being displayed because the element is displayed embedded in the page." To clarify, the URL I am showing is taken by right clicking on the content in SFMC and clicking on 'Copy Link Location'.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Gortonington. I will open a ticket with support becuase I don't have this page when clicking "properties" from a HTML Paste element in my MC account. Some kind of MC Account setup or configuration needs to be done. Thanks again !